# Laravel Lumen Migrations fail if there are no migrations present

Tags: php, laravel, migration, lumen, lumen-5.5

I created a new Lumen project without any migrations for now. Since I'm setting up CI, I'd like to always run `php artisan migrate` just in case migrations are added at some point.

Here is my .env file for the CI server:

```
APP_ENV=testing
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:ROhueDv4THITTXXfOO14HsMNO/Po5hx1eQndrbt12cA=
APP_URL=http://jarvis-testing.easybell.de

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=jarvis_test
DB_USERNAME=dev
DB_PASSWORD=dev

CACHE_DRIVER=file
```

Here is my `database.php` file:

```
<?php

return [
    'default'     => 'mysql',
    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env( 'DB_HOST' ),
            'port'      => env( 'DB_PORT' ),
            'database'  => env( 'DB_DATABASE' ),
            'username'  => env( 'DB_USERNAME' ),
            'password'  => env( 'DB_PASSWORD' ),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        ]
    ]
];
```

When I run `php artisan migrate`, I get the following error:

```
In Connection.php line 664:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '' (SQL: create table `` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)


In Connection.php line 452:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name ''
```

When running `php artisan migrate:status`, the output is:

```
No migrations found.
```

So from my point of view, Lumen should just not do anything at this point. What am I missing here?

Comment: Nice find, go report it to [lumen repository](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/new).

Comment: Hmm, if you take a look at the actual [function that runs the migration](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Migrations/Migrator.php), this shouldn't happen. Maybe open a bug report indeed.

Answer (score 0):

In your migration file, you have to mention the table name in on function.

Example:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('')
    ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

above will show an error so we need to use table name in on function

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
    ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: There is no migration file present.